# Rstudio: mouse follow focus?

Tags: rstudio

Is there a way for Rstudio to get the focus to follow the mouse position between the scripting window and the console?

This is fairly standard behavior to expect and I always end up typing in the wrong window!

Apparently this is supposed [to have been a feature a long time ago](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3020) on MacOS but is not working for me on either Linux or MacOS and I could not find an option to enable it.

Comment: You already found the place where RStudio devs track this exact issue - probably best if you engage with them there.